# why subtracting from pointer in this destructor and assignoperator?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, destructor

Hi I have a test tomarrow and can't figure out why subtraction is made on the pointer before checking if the refcount is 0. I've been searching on google but still cant figure it out. So I'm hoping turning to you guys :) would help. 
Easyiest is too just show you the code, I've marked the lines with comments, so here it is:

This is the class StringRep that has pointers to it for counting pointerref to it,

```
struct StringRep{ 
 int size; // amount of chars incl. EOL \0-tecken 
 char* chars; // Pointer to char 
 int refCount; // Amount of String-variables
};
```

And this is class String that uses the StringRep,

```
class String{ 
public: 
 String(char* str); 
 String(const String& other); 
 ~String(); 
 const String& operator=(const String& rhs); 

 char get(int index) const { return srep->chars[index]; } 
 void put(char ch, int index); 
private: 
 StringRep* srep; 
}; 

String::String(const String& other):srep(other.srep){ 
 srep->refCount++; 
} 

String::~String(){ 
 if (--srep->refCount == 0){  //why --srep here? 
 delete [] srep->chars; 
 delete srep; 
 } 
} 

const String& String::operator=(const String& rhs){ 
 if (srep != rhs.srep){ 
 if (--srep->refCount == 0){  //why --srep here? 
 delete [] srep->chars; 
 delete srep; 
 } 
 srep = rhs.srep; 
 srep->refCount++; 
 } 
 return *this; 
} 

void String::put(char ch, int index){ 
 if (srep->refCount > 1){                  //Why not --srep here?
 StringRep* tmpRep = new StringRep; 
 tmpRep->refCount = 1; 
 tmpRep->size = srep->size; 
 tmpRep->chars = new char[tmpRep->size]; 
 std::strcpy(tmpRep->chars, srep->chars); 
 --srep->refCount; 
 srep = tmpRep; 
 } 
 srep->chars[index] = ch; 
}
```

This is all info I have on the example question for the test, I know that --spek points to the object before spek, but cant figure out the logic behing checking if what is pointed at before now is 0 then its okey to delete, or to copy, but why? As I said I've searched the webb and have found some answers to help me understand the functions of the pointer and the subtraction etc, it more the logic that is confusing.

Best regards

Comment: The operators bind like so: `--(srep->refCount)`

Answer (score 8):

Because of operator precendence, `--srep->refCount` is not decrementing srep, but the refCount member.

So, the code is decrementing the refCount, and if it comes down to 0, it can assume that the last reference to the object is being destroyed.

Comment: Just a last question, so refCount should have a default start value of 1 in this implementation right?

Comment: @MRK187 We don't see the code for the default String constructor, but yes it should be initialising a new StringRep with some default values.

Comment: Actually no, it starts with 0, or else this wouldn't work quite well
 `if (--srep->refCount == 0){`

Comment: Can anybody tell me why in the put function refcount is subtracted when adding a new string object to stringRep?

Comment: @MRK187, Well you usually start with 1, since at creation you have 1 reference holder. Notice this is a prefix decrement, which is done prior checking equality with 0.

Comment: Yeah but in this case an empty representation of StringRep is 0 on the refcount

Comment: @MRK187 This String class is implementing copy-on-write. Basically, if we are not the only holder of that string, we create a new StringRep, copy the data before modifying it, and then we decrement the refcount of *the old one*.

Comment: @MRK187 You should never have a StringRep with refCount == 0. As soon as this happens, it means no one needs that String and then srep is deleted immediately.

Comment: thanks, Put is only putting char in the string value so no String objects are added thats why its no refcount++ in put,
so when adding a new ch in the string value in the put function we basically create a new object of StringRep, but Im not getting why its checking if refcount is more then 1 then create new StringRep, but why is the code putting the tmp->refcount to 1 shouldnt it put it to the old refcount amount?

Comment: @MRK187 We don't want to modify the String for the other references (that is why refcount is check for being greater than 1). So `put` basically duplicates the string's content prior modification. At this point since we have a new String, and that we are its sole owner, the refcount *for this new String* is 1. At this point I would suggest you create yourself a small sample and debug it to see   how the logic goes.

Answer (score 3):

```
--srep->refCount
```

is parsed as

```
--(srep->refCount)
```

because prefix decrement has lower priority than `->` (however, postfix decrement has the same priority as `->`). Always use parens in your own code!

Comment: Can anybody tell me why in the put function refcount is subtracted when adding a new string object to stringRep?, At least it is not counting up when adding?